# How to make HTML page appear the same for all displays?

Tags: html, css

I've recently been tasked with the of making a website for a department in my school. One problem I've encountered is that the webpage will appear differently on all screens and like to know if it exists some kind of tag or way in css to make it auto adjust on all screens.

Comment: You're looking for media queries (and/or percentage widths)

Comment: Look into Twitter bootstrap. You are in need of a responsive design and that should help.

Comment: You want it to look the same, or you want it to look good in every screen?

Comment: you can try with Bootstrap Responsive css http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

There is no easy answer, certainly none that would fit here. Here's a good place to start:

Here is a good introduction to responsive web design, which will help you deal with how your sites will appear on different screen sizes, and different devices. Good luck.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

Comment: please add some content from the link.

Answer (score -2):

Try using media queries. Please check:
[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at responsive CSS: [W3Schools Responsive CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp). This includes information about how to make your own as well as examples of existing popular frameworks such as Bootstrap and Framework.